# how many ads types available for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, admob, iad

Hi every one i am looking ad subscription to my app.Right now i have integrated iAd with my application.here my question is,is any ad services other than iad? if yes,can any one give me some data for other ad services because iAd is not available to all the countries.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the AdMob ad types here: http://helpcenter.admob.com/node/423/